# Updating timestamp of message dynamically in socketio chat application

Tags: javascript, socket.io, momentjs

I am using momentJS for displaying time of chat messages like "a few seconds ago, 1 hour ago".

```
function createChatMsg(msg){

    var timeS = moment(msg.time).fromNow();
    var li = "<li><p class='pull-right'>"+timeS+"  "+msg.data+"</p></li>";
    return li;
}

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    var li = createChatMsg(msg);
    $(".chat").append(li);
});
```

There can be hundreds of such messages with variable "timeS". And they need to be updated each second. How can I achieve this?

Comment: But elements are dynamically created and how to put setInterval for each li element individually?

Comment: have a reference to the array of elements and iterate over that array every time `setInterval`' runs